# Real number has valuation?

Tags: tropical-geometry

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valuation_(algebra)
I know rational number has valuation, p adic valuation but i think that`s not work in real number you know
anyone know?

Comment: Any field has a trivial valuation. The rationals are a subfield of reals so any valuation on reals would reduce to a valuation on the rationals.

Comment: The p-adic valuation doesn't work with the reals directly but it can be extended to a non-archimedean valuation on the reals. "Proofs from the Book" has a proof of this in the appendix to one of their chapters.

Comment: wow thx cyclotomicfield!